Does the pseudepigrapha contain accurate history?
Do pseudepigraphical books such as the testaments of the patriarchs or the gospel of Thomas still contain accurate historical information about the biblical era even if they contain some false doctrine?

Most. if not all, lies contain as much truth as possible to make them credible. Propaganda (nowadays called 'fake news') is loaded with factual information surrounding the lie which is the purpose of the dissemination. So one would expect that people who attempted to mimic scripture would be generous with factual information within their documents. Or persons who thought they were writing scripture would have no reason to leave out genuine report. Or documents wrongly elevated to be 'inspired' would not necessarily be utterly incompetent.


Do pseudepigraphical books such as the testaments of the patriarchs or the gospel of Thomas still contain accurate historical information about the biblical era even if they contain some false doctrine?

It's certainly possible. Your school's history textbook isn't Scripture and probably contains falsehoods; does that mean none of the historical information in it is accurate? Of course not. Josephus' works are not Scripture, but are widely regarded to contain much accurate historical information.
Even clearly fanciful accounts such as the Epic of Gilgamesh (or the Gospel of Thomas) may contain elements of accurate history despite many gratuitous falsehoods.
The Question implies a false dichotomy. Scripture is True. Anything that is not Scripture may be true, or it may not, but simply being not-Scripture doesn't make it false. Veracity must be judged against other factors, including whether it contradicts more reliable sources (e.g. Scripture).
Aside from Scripture, there is no simple answer to "is X true?". One would have to look at specific claims made by X, as X may be entirely true, entirely false, or may contain a mixture of truth and falsehood. Even a statement such as "X contains some accurate historical information" is overly broad; what parts of X are accurate? What parts aren't?
